# serialize class Name in Json

Tags: json.net

I am getting some json data from an extrenal provider and they seem to have the typename in the serialized string
Their serialized json for a collection of Creatives looks like

```
                  {
                  "Creatives": { 
                         "Creative": { 
                                       "AdServerCreativeId": "32", 
                                        "CreativeName": "TSTPLC008_CM43P6890_14" 
                                      } 
                                 } 
                   }
```

normally we expect it to look like

```
                    {
                      "Creatives": [ 
                                        { 
                                          "AdServerCreativeId": "32", 
                                          "CreativeName": "TSTPLC008_CM43P6890_14" 
                                        },
                                        { 
                                           "AdServerCreativeId": "33", 
                                           "CreativeName": "TSTPLC008_CM43P6890_15" 
                                         } 

                                    ]
                     }
```

I don't know how they got the typename (Creative) for each creative in the json but my deserialization using Json.net fails.
Similarly When i send them a request to add creatives they expect the "creative" string to be there in the collection for each creative

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: How JSON should be formatted when there're multiple Creatives? Dictionary key, like in the first example, can't be used to indicate type because keys must be unique.

Comment: I added a wrapper class around the creative class and that did the trick.             public class OriginalCreative { //some properties}                 public class CreativeWrapper { public OriginalCreative Creative {get;set;}              public class Placements { public List<CreativeWrapper> Creatives {get;set;}